# I have error message trying to show a phylogenetic tree using R studio, I can not upload it

Tags: r, phylogeny

I am trying to upload a phylogenetic tree named Symonds.tre that is in my working directory and is **.tre**

```
library(ape)
symondsTree <- read.tree("symonds.tre")
```

**Error message is:**

> Error in if (all(phy$node.label == "")) phy$node.label <- NULL
> :missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Do I have to do something to the labels or nodes, is there something missing?
Thanks for your help,
Y

Comment: `read.tree` isn't part of base R.  So we need to know what package you are using (`data.tree` perhaps?).  We also need to see (at least part of) your tree.  Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) for help on how to create a simple self-contained and reproducible example.  Providing one will help us to help you.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for getting back to me. I am using ape, geiger and caper.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for getting back to me. I am using ape, geiger and caper. The tree i am using is already published tree by Bininda-Emonds et al 2007 mammal super tree. I have a data matrix with some mammal taxa that are also analysis in that phylogeny and want to do a pgls analysis using ape library. Do you want a copy of the tree? thanks Yamila

Comment: @YamilaGurovich did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 3):

for the record, I just ran into this problem, and it seems like I was trying to read in a NEXUS file using `read.tree` from the package ape which only works on Newick format trees. I changed the command to `read.nexus` and that took care of it.

Answer (score -1):

open the .nex in TextEdit and check if it is empty

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."